# .wav file not playing in audio element in HTML 5

Tags: html, audio, wav

I am using following code to play the `.wav` file using the HTML5 audio player.

```
 <audio controls autoplay>
    <source src="test.wav" type="audio/wav">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

The file is not played in the browser. I tried this in both IE Edge and Chrome and it does not work in both.

If I try the `.mp3` format that works.  The documentation on internet seems to suggest that `.wav` format is supported.

Is there some thing wrong in my code. Can we play `.wav` files in IE Edge and Chrome using the HTML5 audio element?

Also if I directly open the `.wav` files in the browsers, then also the files are not played.

Thanks for your time, let me know in case any other information is needed.

**Edit:**
I seems like there is some problem in my `wav` files because if I try files from http://freewavesamples.com/files/Kawai-K11-CleanGtr-C3.wav then it works but not with my local wav files.

Comment: Based on your question and the answers, I think you gave `src`attribute the wrong path : src="test.wav" works only if test.wav is right next to your HTML file. Just to be sure, you can open the JS console to check for 404 responses.

Comment: The file path  is correct. HTML page and audio file are right next to each other in the same root directory.

Answer (score 2):

No, IE / Edge does not support WAV files. See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp , the only common format is MP3.

Oddly enough, WAV is supported by all the other browsers which is strange because WAV is primarily a Windows thing.

Answer (score 0):

> The documentation on internet seems to suggest that .wav format is supported.

You must be reading different documentation to me.

From [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats):

> The WAVE container format, with the PCM audio codec (WAVE codec "1") is supported by desktop/mobile Gecko (Firefox) and Safari.

There is no mention of Chrome or Internet Explorer so, I would presume, they do not support the format. Your experiments support that conclusion.

It isn't a particularly efficient format for transporting audio over a network, so is best avoided anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code and tried with WAV file named "test.wav". Using Chrome, it works for me. So, i think i can confirm there is no error in your code.

In your situation, it could be because of architecture of files.
Sorry for not being able to help you anymore.